# Using sqlite3_bind_XXX inside a loop

Tags: c++, sqlite, prepared-statement

I want to do multiple parameterized inserts with SQLite in my code. For this :

I have a single prepare statement outside of my loop as :

```
error = sqlite3_prepare(connection, insert_sql, strlen(insert_sql), &stmt, NULL);
```

I want inserts within a loop as:

```
while ( not reached end of datafile ) {
    
    // Insert into server table
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt,    1, id1);
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 2, latitude);
    sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 3, longitude);
    
    sqlite3_step(stmt);

}
```

The API docs for the function : https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html
mention that :

> sqlite3_step() has been called more recently than sqlite3_reset(), then the call will return SQLITE_MISUSE
>
> Bindings are not cleared by the sqlite3_reset() routine
>
> If any sqlite3_bind_() routine is passed a prepared statement that has
> been finalized, the result is undefined and probably harmful.

I am really confused as to how do I do repeated inserts with parameterized query in SQLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `sqlite3_reset()` after `sqlite3_step()`.

Comment: If this is a plausible solution, I am not sure what does it mean when the reference mentions : "Bindings are not cleared by the sqlite3_reset() routine"?

Comment: "not cleared" just means that you could execute the statement again, with the same bound values. The `sqlite3_reset()` call *allows* you to apply new bindings.