# Does sqlite bind by reference or by value?

Tags: c, sqlite, parameters, bind

When I bind in sqlite, what actually happens, or essentially am I passing by reference or by value?  If I bind a variable, does sqlite see changes in the value of the variable or is it a one-shot deal?  Binding within the loop tells me I'm misusing the library, even if I clear the bindings at the end of the loop contents with sqlite3_clear_bindings.  Binding first gets me no rows at all, even though the bind returns SQLITE_OK.  (Is it binding a 0?)

```
    int cat;
    sql = "select x,y,z from table where q = ?"
    bind cat (to ?) here
    for (cat=0; cat<topcat; cat++) {
      //  I want (multiple) results for each cat value here
      rslt = 0;
      while ((rslt != SQLITE_DONE) && (rslt != SQLITE_ERROR)) {
        rslt = sqlite3_step(stmt2);
        // do column stuff here to fetch values
      }
    }
```

Another part of the program fetches all the rows from another table OK with no where clause in the SQL.  If I take the where and bind out of this I can get all the rows.  If I bind to a constant value like 3 instead of cat, that works.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are always bound by value.

Strings and blobs can be bound by reference (by using SQLITE_STATIC), but that does not allow to change the length later, and the value itself might be cached elsewhere.

If you want to change the value, you *must* call `sqlite3_bind_*` again.

Furthermore, you can change bindings only after you have called `sqlite3_reset` and before you execute the statement again.

Comment: OK, I just tried sqlite3_reset, I had tried sqlite3_clear_bindings instead.  Now I'm seeing rows.

Comment: Well, no, I'm seeing rows because I changed my loop starting value from 0 to 1, I still don't get rows for any other values. I am binding within the loop, I clear bindings and reset too each iteration.  But I only get rows for the first value.  This question is close but for inserts, not selects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973353/using-sqlite3-bind-xxx-inside-a-loop

Comment: OK, bigger hammer: I completely close the database connection and reconnect each loop iteration, then prepare and bind.  Not an elegant solution but this is a one-time-use program, I just want to get the data into HTML form.  Still runs in under 1 second.  I have limited patience with sqllite, I usually use PostgreSQL or MySql, but I didn't make the database.

Answer (score -1):

C is always pass by value. The only way to pass a reference is to pass in a pointer. In that case you have to take the address of your variable with the `&` operator.

Comment: Actually what I have is an array, which in C is loosely equivalent to a pointer to element 0.  But I want to retain control of my loop control variable because other things like generating different html sections need to happen based on it.  In fact there's another loop, another table, another query inside this one that I haven't written yet.  I use *char all the time, usually not *int.